# DetailView in ASP.NET (C#) in Edit Mode using DropDown list pushing Primary Key to Database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, drop-down-menu, detailsview

How to have primary key fields in Grid and Detail view but show the name field.  And then have drop downs in edit mode.

I have a SQL database that I am connecting to my website through LINQ and using ASP.NET (C#).

The database is a simple equipment inventory database  that has four tables

1. equipment description
2. equipment manufacturer
3. location
4. history of where the equipment is located

The equipment description table has a data field for manufacturer which I populated with the primary key of the equipment manufacturer table.The history table has a data field for the equipment id (primary key) of the equipment description table and a data field for location id (primary key) from the location table.

I can make the connection to the database and I am trying to use Gridviews and Detail Views.

But when I display the equipment table with a grid view or an individual item in a  detail view   I see the manufacturer id  and not the manufacturer name.   I understand that is what I should see.   I can create a  SQL view ( query) where I would have both the manufacturer id and the name and can then show the data field of the manufacturer name. But I know there is a way that I could do this without the query, and have some sort of way in the “Item Template” view to see the manufacturers name .  And in the “Edit Template” view  have a dropdown list  that would pull from the manufacturers table  that would show the manufacturers name  but put the manufacturers id into the data field once one has “Updated” the data.

I have tried looking up tutorials on the web but seem to not be looking up the right words. I get stuck at getting tutorials just showing the dropdown list  and not the step pushing the primary key back into the database.  Or showing the manufactures name when initially displaying the table.
I figure if I can get this to work in the Detail view it will basically be the same type of process for Grid Views.  I am hoping the example does not go too deep into coding and works with the wizard-like tools I am using in Visual studio.  I know asking a lot.

Hopefully someone  can point me to the right video or text tutorial that I can make this work.

Comment: It would be better if you can do some typesetting

Answer (score 0):

It took enough tries that I finally found the resource I was look for and it seems to be working.  I searched for "ASP.NET LINQ GridView DropDownList from secondary Table"  and bingo.

See [Scotts Gu Blog for a LINQ step by step](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/linq-to-sql-part-5-binding-ui-using-the-asp-linqdatasource-control)

See [jSCAP solution for SQLDataSource step by step](https://forums.asp.net/t/963312.aspx?Using%20Gridview%20with%20a%20dropdownlist%20from%20another%20table)